# Optimisation of badly performing Linq query in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq, .net-core

I got the following function, `_Context` is a `databaseContext` and `Users` is a table in the database.

The database consists of ~1 million entries. The Guid of the table `Users` is indexed (see code shown below).

How can I optimize `GetUserByGuid` so that it returns faster? As of now it can take up to a minute to return an answer, which is way too slow.

```
public void GetUserByGuid(string guid, int page, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    var users = _Context.Users
                        .Where(x => x.Guid.Equals(guid) && 
                                    (DateTime.Compare(from.Date, x.TimeDone.Date) <= 0) && 
                                    (DateTime.Compare(x.TimeDone.Date, to.Date) <= 0))
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeDone)
                        .Skip(page * 10)
                        .Take(10)
                        .ToList();
}
```

The `Users` table is created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] 
(
    [Id]       INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeDone] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Guid]     CHAR(64) NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TimeDone]
ON [dbo].[Users]([TimeDone] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Guid]
ON [dbo].[Users]([Guid] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90);
```

Comment: Can you please add generated query SQL?

Comment: `guid` as a `char(64)` ?? Why isn't this a `uniqueidentifier`? Also: if you insist on a string - why is this **64 characters** long - and fixed length (so it will be padded to the defined length with spaces) ?? A regular GUID would be **36** characters (including the dashes) .... Also: the `CHAR` type is non-Unicode - while C# uses Unicode - so you might be incurring a costly "implicit type conversion" in the query here....

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that EF core can translate `DateTime.Compare` into SQL (and if not an you are using EF Core before 3.0 version it will fetch all the data into memory and will perform all operations on the client side) and you don't need it to compare datetimes in your EF query, just compare them directly, to handle the date part only for `toDate` add one day and use exclusive comparison:

```
var fromDate = from.Date;
var toDate = to.Date.AddDays(1);
var users = _Context.Users.Where(x => x.Guid.Equals(guid) && 
                            (from.Date <= x.TimeDone) && 
                            (x.TimeDone < to.Date))
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeDone)
                            .Skip(page * 10)
                            .Take(10)
                            .ToList();
```

Or use [`DbFunctions.DateDiffDay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.datediffday?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions_DateDiffDay_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctions_System_DateTime_System_DateTime_):

```
DbFunctions.DateDiffDay(from, x.TimeDone) >= 0 
&& DbFunctions.DateDiffDay(x.TimeDone, to) >= 0 // if I have not messed the comparison order
```